# Angular 6 Karma Tests running tests from libs folder rather than app source

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine

The company I work for asked me to write some karma tests for their angular app.

THe current folder structure is as follows

both apps and libs are located on the root

> apps 
>   - appone 
>   - apptwo 
>   - etc
>
> libs 
>   - all components are in here since they are used across apps

I want to test the tests I've written for the different components that are in the libs folder but karma always points to the app and tests the app itself.

Is there any way to specify the folder it should use? or which test.ts to use that's not in one of the apps?

I've been looking all over and haven't found a solution to this problem as of yet.

Comment: Each lib is probably setup as a project within the `angular.json`? You should just be able to run `ng test libname`. Not sure how to run `appone` specific tests though, including app + libs relevant to that project